# Keynote master slide

Tags: keynote

I have keynote 11 on iPad 6th. Somehow I cannot find ways to edit or create master slide. I cannot get the option when I press show view button or paint button.Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ask Different!

### To create a master slide which Apple calls a slide layout:

1. **Tap any blank area on an existing slide in your presentation** and then tap "Edit Slide Layout" on the pop-up menu that comes out,
2. Tap the plus (+) sign at the bottom of the slight navigator to appear on the left,
3. Select an existing slide layout that looks similar to what  you want on the slight navigator again by tapping on it,
4. Type a name for the new slide layout, and then tap Done.
5. Make the changes you wish to the new slide layout and tap Done when finished with editing.

### To edit an existing slide layout:

1. **Tap any blank area on an existing slide in your presentation** and then tap "Edit Slide Layout" on the pop-up menu that comes out,
2. Tap to select the slide layout you want to edit,
3. Make the changes you wish to the slide layout and then tap Done.

You can find more details on these in this [Keynote for iPad Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote-ipad/add-and-edit-slide-layouts-tan7a2b69972/11.1/ipados/1.0).

Comment: Thank you very much Alper. I didn’t know that Keynote had changed the way to create the so called Master Slide.

Comment: No problem. Pls don’t forget to mark my answer as “accepted” if it has indeed answered your question(s).